# Am I misreading the statistics? (Chrome 71.4% of market share)

Tags: browsers

I headed over to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) to find out how the browser competition looks like at the moment. I was stunned to see that Chrome was reported as 71.4 percent. That seems incredibly high even considering it is both desktop and mobile. Am I missing something or is Chrome really crushing the competition that much?

Comment: At the top of the w3schools page you link to, it states: "collected from W3Schools' log-files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

71.4% of *w3schools users* use chrome, not the world as whole. w3schools' audience are programmers who tend to use Chrome because they are more technical than the average user and know that is is better than IE and (arguably) better than Firefox. They also like it's very powerful developer tools which obviously makes their web development easier.

When you get the statistics from other providers who get their data from multiple sites that are not technical in nature the [market share of Chrome is about 48% according to NetMarketshare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=0) which gets their data from over 40,000 different websites which helps to eliminate the bias you get from using only one website for your data.